# Metal: Textures loaded from alpha-less .png files don't display correctly

Tags: objective-c, graphics, png, metal

I'm working on porting a graphics system based on CoreGraphics to use Metal instead. However, I've noticed that there seems to be some kind of color system mixup when I load .png files that do not have an alpha channel. .png's with an alpha channel work fine, although I have to do some swizzling as my Metal context uses BGR colors. When I load and display a texture from an alpha-less .png, the color components appear to be out of order. Textures that were supposed to appear red appear blue and vice-versa, leading me to believe the order of the color components has been swapped.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? There was no issue on the previous CG-based system.

Comment: You shouldn't need to swizzle just because the a texture you're reading from/writing to is in BGRA order. Reading/sampling always produces components in RGBA order. I have, however, heard of other instances where PNG handling produced inconsistencies in component order. Can you describe *exactly* how you create your textures? In particular, are you using `MTKTextureLoader`?

Comment: @warrenm actually, I just realized that the problem is that the alpha-less textures are in the _right_ order, and the ones with alpha are in the wrong order, and I didn't need to be swizzling. But yes, I'm using `MTKTextureLoader` and calling `newTextureWithContentsOfURL` on a URL that leads to the file. I'm not supplying any extra options.